# While, switch, fgets for menu

Tags: c

I am trying to make a menu that uses fgets instead of scanf() since scanf() isn't safe to use in term of wrong input.
The problem I am having is that the loop doesn't wait for input like it would had if I had used a scanf() instead of fgets().
My plan is to use fgets() to read a char and then using atoi() to make the char to an integer.

```
int main()
{
    fordon_t fordon[1];
    char cVal[2];
    int menyVal;

    lasFranFil(fordon);
    while(menyVal != 6);
    {
        prompt();
        //Varför väntar den inte på input här?
        fgets(cVal, sizeof(cVal), stdin);
        switch (menyVal)
        {
            case 1: //ADDERAFORDON:
                adderafordon(fordon);
                break;
            case 2: //SUBTRAHERAFORDON:
                tabortfordon();
            case 3: //SORTERING:
                break;
            case 4:
            break;
            case AVSLUTA:
                skrivTillFil(fordon);
                
                break;
            
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some of the code is not finished but it doesn't affect the "menu" part of the program. What I am looking for is an example on how to make a menu and using fgets() as input

Comment: If you want to read just one character, then use `getchar`

Comment: `fgets` returns a string. You can convert to int with a function like `strtol`. Or compare using chars: `case '1':`, etc. Note that `fgets` adds the newline in the returned string so you might want to make `cVal` larger.

Comment: Just to know, why do you want to read the input as char and then convert it to int instead of reading it as int? And what is this case meant to do? `case AVSLUTA`

Comment: Davide: Getchar might have worked the way I wanted but I managed to find a way with fgets and I am trying to stay consistent with that throughout the whole program.

Johnny mop: Since the menu just have options 1-6 I only need the space for one char and the end of string character.

Davide (2): Since I want to use fgets and fgets only reads strings I need to convert it into an int, the case AVSLUTA is writing the contents of the array to a file. AVSLUTA is defined as 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i solved it. The problems I had where solved by the do while loop instead of while and the atoi to make char into an int.

```
    #include "MAINHEAD.h"

int main()
{
    fordon_t fordon[10];
    //fordon_t fordon = calloc(ANTALFORDON, (sizeof(fordon_t)));
    char cVal[2];
    int menyVal = 0;

    lasFranFil(fordon);
    do 
    {
        prompt();
        //Varför väntar den inte på input här?
        fgets(cVal, sizeof(cVal), stdin);
        menyVal = atoi(cVal);
        switch (menyVal)
        { 
            case ADDERAFORDON:
                adderafordon(fordon);
                break;
            case SUBTRAHERAFORDON:
                tabortfordon();
            case SORTERING:
                break;
            case 4:
            //SKriv ut info om ett fordon på position.
            break;
            case SKRIVUT:
            skrivUt();
            break;
            case AVSLUTA:
                skrivTillFil(fordon);
                break;
            
            default:
                break;
        } 
    }while(menyVal !=6); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fgets return a string,

You have to return caracetr ,you can use getchar() or sscanf() whichever comforts more

Example :

```
char ch;

ch = getchar();
```

Comment: That might have worked the way i wanted to but i wanted to use fgets instead.